# How to access a the database data for Lexik Translation Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using the Lexik Trnaslation Bundle.

After I ran

```
./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

It added some tables to my database. These tables however don't have any Entities or Repository Classes.

How can I fetch the Data from these tables?
Is this even possible with doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are entity classes and repository classes mapped to these new tables, or course. Otherwise `doctrine:schema:update` wouldn't create any tables at all.

If you take a look at the source code of the plugin, you'll see the corresponding classes [here](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/tree/master/Entity).

The repositories are:

- `FileRepository`
- `TransUnitRepository`
- `TranslationRepository`

These repositories are not declared as services, so you won't be able to inject them directly. But you can inject the `ManagerRegistryInterface` and get the repository like this:

```
// example to get the FileRepository, assuming that $this->manager
// holds the EntityManager

$fileRepository = $this
            ->manager
            ->getRepository(Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Entity\File::class);
```

Comment: Okay I understand. But when i try to fetch something like so  
`$a = $this->transUnitRepository->findAll();
        dd($a);`
I get the following error `Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\Api\MyController": argument "$transUnitRepository" of method "__construct()" references class "Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Entity\TransUnitRepository" but no such service exists.`

Comment: You'll need to get the repository from the EntityManagerInterface. These are not registered as services, but the Entity Manager knows about them.